# JSON schema with data containing external data

Tags: json, schema

Say I have a JSON object which looks like this:

```
{
  "identifier": "carModels",
  "friendlyName": "Car Models",      
  "dataType": "int",   
  "isRequired": false,
  "format": null,   
  "selectableOptions": {
    "url": "http://some-service-resources/carmodels",
    "displayPropertyName": "value1",
    "valuePropertyName": "name",
    "selectMode": "single"
  }
}
```

I can easily use an online tool to create the JSON schema which looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "identifier": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "friendlyName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "dataType": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "isRequired": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "format": {
      "type": "null"
    },
    "selectableOptions": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "url": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "displayPropertyName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "valuePropertyName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "selectMode": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "url",
        "displayPropertyName",
        "valuePropertyName",
        "selectMode"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "identifier",
    "friendlyName",
    "dataType",
    "isRequired",
    "format",
    "selectableOptions"
  ]
}
```

This schema, and data, however, does not give the full picture.  It does not contain a definition of car models, retrievable from http://some-service-resources/carmodel, nor does it contain the possible options for selectableOptions.selectMode, which could be single or multiple.

How does one handle this?

Comment: What do you mean by definition of carModels?

Comment: Its schema.  What properties it contains, etc.